# Propagate values in a multi index dataframe when index value does not exist

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, reindex

I have a multi-index dataframe resulting from a `groupby()` as follows:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['date', 'name']).agg({'ABC': 'sum'})
df_grouped
                   ABC
date        name 
01-03-2018  Adam   1
            John   2
01-04-2018  Adam   4
            Sam    1
01-05-2018  Adam   5
            John   3
            Sam    2
01-06-2018  Jake   1
```

I want to propagate the ABC values forward in `date` only if the `name` does not exist in the new `date`. If it exists, then it should be left as it is:

```
                   ABC
date        name 
01-03-2018  Adam   1
            John   2
01-04-2018  Adam   4
            John   2
            Sam    1
01-05-2018  Adam   5
            John   3
            Sam    2
01-06-2018  Jake   1
            Adam   5
            John   3
            Sam    2
```

I am not sure how to do this efficiently without looping over each `date`. Is there a better way, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = df_grouped.unstack().ffill().stack().astype(int)
                 ABC
date       name     
01-03-2018 Adam    1
           John    2
01-04-2018 Adam    4
           John    2
           Sam     1
01-05-2018 Adam    5
           John    3
           Sam     2
01-06-2018 Adam    5
           Jake    1
           John    3
           Sam     2
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I tried it and it works.